# How reset all fields in react native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I want to reset all fields and options after submitting. i.e I want to reload the screen after submitting. I'm using the bottom nav tab .how do I achieve this?? in react native expo.
-- another way than using setState for every field.

Comment: Can you share your code? After submitting, you can call a function that resets the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save all field data in state and also need to provide that state in fields as well and try to clear state it will clear field as well

Comment: lets say I have 4,5 useState hooks. I'll need to reset all state. is there any another way?

Comment: please don't create multiple states manage all in one useState with the object and update that state every time

Comment: Ohh thanks. but can you please explain what's are disadvantageous of multiple state hooks??